# Выбрать видимые элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть контейнер который содержит группу элементов, пример в сниппете.

Он имеет определенную ширину которая может меняться и содержит стиль `overflow: hidden`, т.е. часть элементов не видна.

```css
.list {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}
.list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
  <li>text 5</li>
  <li>text 6</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно при помощи JavaScript или jQuery выбрать только те **li** которые видны в пределах ширины 200px; но нужно учитывать тот момент, что эта ширина может быть разная и может меняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простого пути нету. По крайней мере я не нашёл.
Можно так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#show').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let li = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list li')).filter(e => e.isVisible(e));
    
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = li.map(e => e.textContent).join('<br />');
  });
});


// From https://gist.github.com/jasonfarrell/3659166
/**
 * Author: Jason Farrell
 * Author URI: http://useallfive.com/
 *
 * Description: Checks if a DOM element is truly visible.
 * Package URL: https://github.com/UseAllFive/true-visibility
 */
Element.prototype.isVisible = function() {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * Checks if a DOM element is visible. Takes into
   * consideration its parents and overflow.
   *
   * @param (el)      the DOM element to check if is visible
   *
   * These params are optional that are sent in recursively,
   * you typically won't use these:
   *
   * @param (t)       Top corner position number
   * @param (r)       Right corner position number
   * @param (b)       Bottom corner position number
   * @param (l)       Left corner position number
   * @param (w)       Element width number
   * @param (h)       Element height number
   */
  function _isVisible(el, t, r, b, l, w, h) {
    var p = el.parentNode,
      VISIBLE_PADDING = 2;

    if (!_elementInDocument(el)) {
      return false;
    }

    //-- Return true for document node
    if (9 === p.nodeType) {
      return true;
    }

    //-- Return false if our element is invisible
    if (
      '0' === _getStyle(el, 'opacity') ||
      'none' === _getStyle(el, 'display') ||
      'hidden' === _getStyle(el, 'visibility')
    ) {
      return false;
    }

    if (
      'undefined' === typeof(t) ||
      'undefined' === typeof(r) ||
      'undefined' === typeof(b) ||
      'undefined' === typeof(l) ||
      'undefined' === typeof(w) ||
      'undefined' === typeof(h)
    ) {
      t = el.offsetTop;
      l = el.offsetLeft;
      b = t + el.offsetHeight;
      r = l + el.offsetWidth;
      w = el.offsetWidth;
      h = el.offsetHeight;
    }
    //-- If we have a parent, let's continue:
    if (p) {
      //-- Check if the parent can hide its children.
      if (('hidden' === _getStyle(p, 'overflow') || 'scroll' === _getStyle(p, 'overflow'))) {
        //-- Only check if the offset is different for the parent
        if (
          //-- If the target element is to the right of the parent elm
          l + VISIBLE_PADDING > p.offsetWidth + p.scrollLeft ||
          //-- If the target element is to the left of the parent elm
          l + w - VISIBLE_PADDING < p.scrollLeft ||
          //-- If the target element is under the parent elm
          t + VISIBLE_PADDING > p.offsetHeight + p.scrollTop ||
          //-- If the target element is above the parent elm
          t + h - VISIBLE_PADDING < p.scrollTop
        ) {
          //-- Our target element is out of bounds:
          return false;
        }
      }
      //-- Add the offset parent's left/top coords to our element's offset:
      if (el.offsetParent === p) {
        l += p.offsetLeft;
        t += p.offsetTop;
      }
      //-- Let's recursively check upwards:
      return _isVisible(p, t, r, b, l, w, h);
    }
    return true;
  }

  //-- Cross browser method to get style properties:
  function _getStyle(el, property) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
      return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[property];
    }
    if (el.currentStyle) {
      return el.currentStyle[property];
    }
  }

  function _elementInDocument(element) {
    while (element = element.parentNode) {
      if (element == document) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  return _isVisible(this);

};
```

```css
.list {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
}
.list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
  <li>text 5</li>
  <li>text 6</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='show' value='Show only visible elements' />
<br /><br />
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно измерять отступ по ширине и смотреть, уходят ли элементы за рамки

```
var container = $('.list'),
    elements = $('li', container),
    checkOffset = container.width() + container.offset().left;

elements.each(function(){
    if ($(this).offset().left > checkOffset) $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Есть проблема с вычислением offset контейнера, где лежат элементы (не учитывается стандартный margin почему-то), но это нюансы.
https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/n5xze73g/

Comment: Нужно использовать outerWidth(true) тогда он все отступы будет учитывать )))